# Failed Linking File Resource

Tags: android

> ```
> Android resource linking failed
> ```
>
> Output:  D:\Study & Project\New folder\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_day.xml:94: error: attribute prayer (aka app.com.temanhijrah:prayer) not found.

error: failed linking file resources.

---------- Layout File

```
  <app.com.temanhijrah.PrayerView
            android:id="@+id/prayer_fajr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:prayer="fajr"/>
```

[Class File](https://pastebin.com/DqCA6MGk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `attrs.xml` file.

in that file there is `declare-styleable` in this you have to declare `prayer` attribute as a `string`.

Comment: thank you very much, i've been stuck in here for 2 days